# Refactoring nested each loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, design-patterns, each, bsearch

I need to do a search comparing two hashs

I use an each to iterate over a hash and b_search to do the binary search:

```
 @player.each do |player|
  player_support_search =  players_support.bsearch { |player_support| player_support[:score] >= player[:score] }
  number_player_support_search [player_support_search [:id]] += 1 unless player_support_search .nil?
 end
```

Is there any pattern where I can refactor to use only one loop?